# Embedded Javascript code to Flutter Mobile

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart

I have to add a script code for spinner of javascript inside the flutter code for mobile Application.

I tried several approaches to implement the script by using WebView and also I put the script directly in JS file then put it in HTML file but non of these approaches run the javascript code on mobile app.

**Question**

Is there any way to embed the javascript code inside the flutter code?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, without webviews, check out this package

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_js

Answer (score 0):

There are several plugins for this but Personality I prefer this one

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin/example

this plugin allows you embbed javaScript code